# Control the frequency of saving data of rosbag record?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to control the frequency of saving data with rosbag record I want them just collect the data at the frequency of 100Hz, not more or less.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261540/control-the-frequency-of-saving-data-of-rosbag-record?/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it's just one topic, you can throttle the topic to whatever frequency you want. It will be re-published to a topic of a different name, though. [topic_tools/throttle](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle)

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on 2017-05-11**:
I need to control the frequency of 2 ROS topics, it is not possible with topic_tools/throttle?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-05-11**:
You'll just need 2 throttle nodes, then.